# WP: How can I show all user_meta fields?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

```
<?php 
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;

$user_fields = get_user_meta( $user_id, , 'true' ); 
echo $user_fields;
?>
```

It showing 'Array'. I would want to know the field to be used on counting the number of times the user logins.

Comment: `print_r` is probably something you wanted

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
var_dump($user_fields)
```

It would show you the variable content !

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$user_fields = get_user_meta( $user_id ); 
print_r($user_fields);
```

it will showing all meta field regarding $user_id

Answer (score 0):

1. In wordpress there is no any pre-defined functionality is available
   for get user login count.. You have to options for doing this..
   either create a plugin or write the follwing custom code on
   functions.php file..
2. Here I have create a variable `user_login_count` in user meta key in regards to user id, so everytime user successfully login, i m increasing the user count by 1..

   ```
   function ulc_my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user) {
   //is there a user to check?
   global $user, $wpdb;
   if (isset($user->ID)) {
         if ( get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_login_count', true) ){
           $user_login_count = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_login_count', true);
           $user_login_count++;
           update_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_login_count', $user_login_count);            
         }else{
             add_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_login_count', '1');
         }                  
   }
   return $redirect_to;
   ```

   }

   add_filter('login_redirect', 'ulc_my_login_redirect', 10, 3);

By using this filter you can get the key value of 'user_login_count' user get_post_meta function..